# how do I implement a "table of contents" for my quiz code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script to show my quiz. One question is shown at a time, and when you click next the old question fades out and the new question fades in.

I also made a table that references the questions -- the table is generated with more js. I want to make it so that when I click on etc "Question 1", the current displayed question fades out and Question 1 fades in (I'm saying fade here but really the animation is instant as you can tell). If I click on "Question 2" the same thing occurs excepts Question 2 fades in. **The point of this table is so you can navigate through all the questions using the table**.

I realize that a "previous button" would be more intuitive in this case, but for various reasons I don't want a previous button.

Here's a snippet of what I have so far:

```js
var totalQuestions = $('.questions').length;
var currentQuestion = 0;

var $questions = $('.questions');
$questions.hide();
$($questions[currentQuestion]).fadeIn(0);

$('#btn-next').click(function() {

  $($questions[currentQuestion]).fadeOut(0, function() {
    currentQuestion++;
    if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
      //do something here
    } else {
      $($questions[currentQuestion]).fadeIn(0);
    }
  });
  tableControl(totalQuestions);
})

var tableControl = function(numberOfQuestions) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    $('#quiz-table').append(

      "<tr>" +
      "<td> <a> Question " + (i + 1) + " </a></td>" +

      "</tr>"

    );

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h1>Quiz 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio">1<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">2<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">3<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">4</br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio">1<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">2<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">3<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">4</br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>Question 3</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio">1<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">2<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">3<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">4</br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>Question 4</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio">1<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">2<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">3<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio">4</br>
    </form>
</div>
<input type="button" id='btn-next' value="Next">
<table id='quiz-table'>
  <tr>
    <th>Question</th>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158185/how-do-i-jump-to-a-specific-element - please ask one question at a time and update the original question with clarifications

Answer (score 1):

You can use the row index to reference index of question

```
$('#quiz-table').on('click', 'tr',function(){
    var rowIdx = $(this).index();
    // hide all, show the corresponding indexed one
    $('.questions').hide().eq(rowIdx-1).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: yeah this looks really good, thanks. I used data attributes to solve it previously but I thought it was much too messy. you just have to do `rowIdx - 1` though so you jump to the right question.

Comment: Indexing should be same no? Unless you have a heading row

Comment: I do yeah. `<th>Question</th>` unless I'm missing something. I'm still learning.

Comment: OK... am guilty of not looking at html in question. `-1` would be right